# Rspec -- need to stub File.open that gets called in another file

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, mocking, stubbing

In my test I'm initializing a new class called `Package` with some parameters.

In the initialization of this class, I open a file that is available on my remote boxes but not something that is commonly there locally. I was wondering how I would go about stubbing that method in my test.

I'm using rspec and mocha. I tried something like:

```
File.stubs(:open).with(:file).returns(File.open("#{package_root}/test_files/test.yml"))
```

I had this line before I initialized `Package` in my test.

I got this error:

```
unexpected invocation: File.open('package/test_files/test.yml')
   satisfied expectations:
   - allowed any number of times, not yet invoked: File.open(:file)
```

I'm not that familiar with rspec or mocha, so help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure you need that `.with(:file)` part, try dropping it altogether.  Also, I believe by specifying it that way you are literally telling it to expect someone to call that method and pass it a  `:file` symbol rather than e.g. a string filename.  Also consider preloading the test YAML file and just returning that:

```
let(:file_like_object) { double("file like object") }

File.stub(:open).and_return(file_like_object)
```

Comment: I changed `File.stub(:open).and_return(...` with `File.stubs(:open).returns(...` and it works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

The new syntax for stubs looks like this:

```
allow(File).to receive(:open).with('file_name').and_return(file_like_object)
```